# CAML Query

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I'd like to have a CAML query to get the events from a calendar list.

I want to get all the events including Today in the upcoming 30 or so days.

So far I have:

```
<Where>
  <DateRangesOverlap>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" />
      <Value Type=\"DateTime\">
        <Today />
      </Value>
    </Geq>
    <FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\" />
    <FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\" />
    <Value Type=\"DateTime\">
      <Month />
    </Value>
  </DateRangesOverlap>
</Where>
```

This does not work :( Any ideas?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, how doesn't it work? Also can you paste in the code where you make the query?

Comment: For which SharePoint version you have posted this question.

Answer (score 3):

As Nat has said you hint (but don't specify) that you are using recurring events in your calendar list so I am assuming that is the part that's not working?

You need to set the `SPQuery.ExpandRecurrances` and `SPQuery.CalendarDate` property prior to running the CAML query and you can only do this using the object model, not the web services or by setting an attribute in CAML.

Further - IIRC this will only expand out instances of recurring events that occur in the same calendar month as `.CalendarDate` so you have to run it multiple times to get a multi-month view.

This is by far the best reference covering recurring events I have found.

- [Understanding the SharePoint Calendar and how to export it to iCal format](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/05/14/understanding-the-sharepoint-calendar-and-how-to-export-it-to-ical-format.aspx)

Welcome to the nightmare of recurring events in SharePoint!

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence does not actually add all the events into the list, but the CAML can only query from "actual" events stored in the list.